# is it possible to make DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(int value) accept timeout time in milliseconds?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

I am trying to write a java code which creates a Oracle JDBC connection to a database using the following type of code:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver()); 
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
```

now I want to close or terminate this connection if it takes more than 200millisecs. I found that they have a method for this which is `setLoginTimeout(int seconds)` that only takes time in seconds is it possible to `setLoginTimeout` in milliseconds? If not, is there any other option to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Oracle OJDBC driver there are properties for managing timeouts in milliseconds. As per [`OracleConnection` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html) there are:

- `CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` - login timeout in ms
- `CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_READ_TIMEOUT` - general read timeout in ms

You can configure them when obtaining a new connection with [`DriverManager.getConnection(url, props)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection(java.lang.String,java.util.Properties)):

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("user", user);
props.setProperty("password", pass);
props.setProperty(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, "200");
props.setProperty(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_READ_TIMEOUT, "200");
DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.. can you explain the difference between setLoginTimeout and CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_CONNECT_TIMEOUT ?? Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you know CONNECTION_PROPERTY_THIN_NET_CONNECT_TIMEOUT is in milliseconds. As far as I'm aware, this is tied to the CONNECT_TIMEOUT TNS property which - afaik - is also in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

`DriverManager.setLoginTimeout` specifies a global default for all JDBC drivers in the application. It is not possible to set it in milliseconds, given [`DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(int seconds)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#setLoginTimeout-int-) is defined as

> Sets the maximum time in seconds that a driver will wait while
>   attempting to connect to a database once the driver has been
>   identified.
>
> **Parameters:**
>      `seconds` - the login time limit in seconds; zero means there is no limit

You will need to use a driver specific configuration property instead (if available).

I'm not sure if Oracle has this, because `oracle.net.CONNECT_TIMEOUT` as suggested by Karol is - as far as I know - also defined in seconds (based on [TCP.CONNECT_TIMEOUT in sqlnet.ora documentation](http://TCP.CONNECT_TIMEOUT))